# Mocking Globals to test browser modules in node

Tags: javascript, node.js, testing, es6-modules

I have some JavaScript modules which consume and declare globals. I'm aware that this is an anti-pattern, but it's a stopgap solution: until our dependencies come around to publishing their own ES module versions, we destructure them from globals. Here's what we do with Redux, as an example.

```
// Example: instead of
import createStore from '../path/to/redux.js';
// we do
const {createStore} = Redux;
```

This works a treat in the browser, and when the dependencies update it will be simple to refactor, however, testing in node with mocha is a different story:

```
// myReducer.test.mjs

import reducer from '../../src/redux-modules/myReducer';
import initialState from '../../src/redux-modules/myReducer';

export default function videosReducerTests() {
  assert('reducer', function() {
    it('should return initial state by default', function() {
      reducer({}, {}).should.equal(initialState);
    });
  });
}
```

I've installed `@std/esm` to help node work with es modules, and set up my package.json with the following:

```
"devDependencies": {
  "@std/esm": "^0.14.0",
},
"@std/esm":"js",
"scripts": {
  "redux-test": "node -r @std/esm test/redux/index.mjs",
}
```

The result of running `yarn redux-test` is

```
ReferenceError: Redux is not defined
```

I've tried mocking the namespaces I need with `global.Redux = {createStore: Function}` etc. at the top of my test files, but those are all ignored, since imports are 'hoisted'.

Any tips on how to get around this block?

Answer (score 0):

You might just stick with importing the full `redux`. It's small enough and may simplify browser/node things.